# Open Django form with AJAX request

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-forms

I am trying to learn django and Javascript(jquery, ajax).
Note: I am new withn this two language (JAVASCRIPT and PYTHON).
My scenario:
I have a html table with the info of some providers. I insert a link to the edit form (django form modelbased). I take the Id of the provider from the html table with an javascript function and pass this value as argument to the edit form. 
This is the function to get the id of the provider, pass it as argument and open the edit form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function param(){
 $(function(){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = tbl.rows;
  var url = "/recepcion/";
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   rows[i].onclick =  function(){
   idpro = this.cells;
   ano = this.cells;
   mes1 = this.cells;
   $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type:"POST",
    url: "/recepcion/",
    datatype: "json",
    data: ({idprov: idpro[0].innerHTML }),
    success: function(data){
      http.open("POST",url,true),
      http.send(data)
        }
  });
   }
  }
 });
}
</script>
```

This is my django view:

```
def RecepcionView(request):
    idp = request.POST.get('idprov')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(request.POST, instance=r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = RecepcionForm(instance=r)

    return render_to_response('recepcion.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get the error: **DetalleRecepcion matching query does not exist**. I know what this error mean. No record match with my filters.
I see in the firebug console and the function take the value from the html table pass it to the form but I don't know why I get this error and the edit form is not rendered.

I know the error is a noob error. but being new in the two language is difficult because I don't know if the error is in the django view or in the AJAX POST function.

I need a little help please.

Thanks

Comment: Your DetalleReception lookup is failing to find an object that matches the parameters you gave it. Does it do this every time you load the page, or only when you try to POST? If it's every time you load the page, are you giving 'anio' and 'mes' values before using them as variables in your lookup? If it's only on post, does the debug page show you what variables were sent to be used in the lookup?

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply. I test my view with a simple form with 3 input text and works fine. the view receive the arguments and rendered the edit form in the template "recepcion" without any problem. the error is triggered when I try to pass the values with the AJAX(jquery) function. In the firebug consoles i can see the values passed as argument and the view must to render with any problem. I don't why this work with when I send the values from a form but doesn't work with the jax function. If you knows the proper way to pass parameter with ajax with GET or POST method let me know please